# JPG into div JS + loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, jpeg

I just want to do this:

```html
<div id="photos">
  <script>
    var i=0;
    for (i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
      document.createElement("<img src=\"" +"i/"+ i + ".jpg\"/>");
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

But it's not working. What's wrong?

Comment: Do not use `document.write` for adding DOM elements. Use `document.createElement`. The linked question shows the how!

Comment: Could you please help me a little bit more?
Whats wrong?
var i=0;
     for (i=0;i<=5;i++)
     {
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = "'i/'+ i + '.jpg\'/>";
     }

Comment: Sure. Looks like there are extraneous quotes in the `img.src = ...` line. Also you don't add the element to DOM of the page. `document.body.appendChild(img)`.

Comment: @undefined  
Could you please help me a little bit more?)

Comment: Sure. I have reopened the question and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of creating DOM elements is using the `document.createElement` API. Here is an example:

```
var i = 0, 
// Defining a temporary variable called tempImg, using `var` in the `for` body is a bad idea
tempImg, 
// Select and cache the target parent element
targetParentElement = document.querySelector('#photos');

for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  //  create an HTMImageLElement object
  tempImg = document.createElement("img");
  // without beggining `/` the `src` has a relative path.
  tempImg.src = "i/" + i + ".jpg";
  tempImg.alt = "the image wasn't found on this server. Check the path!";
  // append the image
  targetParentElement.appendChild(tempImg);
}
```

Here is a demo on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/udju8mzt/

Comment: Thank you!
And don't you know why it duplicates photos when i put this code in to <script> html?

Comment: You are welcome! Can you provide a demo and reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sorry, it was mine mistake. I've just put incorrect number to "i <=". Now it is OK. Thank you so much!

Comment: That's great. You are welcome! I'm glad I could help!